# getting the source of jsp page along with the required data when exporting to csv file on clicking of a link on screen

Tags: jsp, csv

When I try to **export data into csv** html code of the whole page is also coming along with the data.

I tried using the following code.

```
Response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName.concat(extn) + "\"");
response.setContentType("application/csv");
```

Comment: Please add relevant info ... Where is this piece of code ? In the JSP itself, in a servlet ?

Comment: this piece of code is in backing bean

Comment: and junk data is of source code of my jsp where my download link is which on clicking invokes the backing bean function where my code is written

Comment: I sorry but my crystal ball is currently dysfunctionning :-(, with so little information I cannot imagine what happens.

Comment: response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
  response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename="
    + fileName.concat(extn));


  try{
   cachedRowData = consumeDao.exportEmpUnitsToExcel(strHiddenBtchEndDate);
   log.debug("size"+cachedRowData.size());
   PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
   /*ServletOutputStream out1=response.getOutputStream();*/
   /*ZipOutputStream output = new ZipOutputStream(out1);
         output.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName.concat(".csv")));*/
   
   ResultSetMetaData 
  

   
   /**
    *

Comment: can anybody tell me what could be the problem

Comment: Show the interaction between the JSP that is displayed *along with the data* and the backing bean, before your question is closed for lack of information. And please do it by editing your post, code in comment is pretty ugly.

Comment: I am unable to post a=the code

Answer (score 1):

I have got similar issue ealier .I have fixed the issue by setting the return type as null

Orginal code(before fixing)

```
    public String ***( HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {


**************************************
some code

**************************************

            response.setContentType("application/csv");   
            response.setHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename="+****.get****()+".txt"); // set the file name to whatever required..
            ServletOutputStream  writer = response.getOutputStream();   

            writer.print("***");
            writer.print("\t");
            writer.print("****");
            writer.print("\t");
            writer.println();


        for(int i=0;i<***.get****().size();i++){

            writer.print(""+***.get****().get(i).get***());

**********************************
somecode
*********************


        return "jsp name";

    }
```

And i have fixed the same by giving ***return null*** instead of  ***return "jsp name";***

Now no junk data or jsp codes are appending to the file.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like **during processing of the same query** you first begin to execute your JSP to process the request from client browser, and then before *the response is committed* you change the headers to declare a content type of `application/csv`. But at that time, the JSP has already written output to the response, or if the bean is included, the jsp will continue to write into the response after writing the content of the csv file.

In either case, the output from the JSP will be mixed with the csv.

To avoid it, you must use a `Servlet` for , and put your code in its `doGet` or `service` method, without passing by a JSP.

But I'm unsure whether it is the actual problem because of the lack of details.

Comment: could you tell me your email id

Comment: and i have a download link on my  page through which backing bean gets hit and its method gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas,
Even i have the same problem. I've tried the solution that you gave, but even that doesn't solve this problem.
It's working fine in my local development environment where we are using JBoss server, but the source code gets appended to the file(only csv and txt extension) in our prod env where we are using weblogic server. 
I had tried with octet-stream as the content type and even with corresponding mime type based on the extension, but nothing seems to work.

And seems like the response already has the source codes, on top of which we are appending the file contents.

Comment: response.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+ filename); fistrm = new FileInputStream(path+File.separator+branchCode+File.separator+filename); bout = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream())while((bytesRead = fistrm.read(buffer)) > -1){ bout.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); bytesBuffered += bytesRead; if(bytesBuffered > 1048576){ bytesBuffered = 0; bout.flush(); }}

Comment: it got solved i returned null instead of jsp page. but not sure how it was working with applucation running on jboss